# Fabric.js: Is there a way to make the "move" listener fire when moved as part of a selection?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there a way to make the "move" listener fire when the object is moved as part of a selection?

```
rect2 = new fabric.Rect(
  left: 150
  top: 10
  fill: "green"
  width: 20
  height: 20
)

# Red&Green Rect: When moving "green", event fires, when moving both, it does not
rect2.on "moving", ->
    #Only fires when the object is moved on it´s own :(
```

jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/mJjH6/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all group objects via `event.target._objects` in canvas `object:moving` event. Note that fabric does not change child coordinates when moving group, so you should add child left coordinate to group left coordinate to get real left position.

Look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqDLt/) example

Comment: Thanks so much for not only answering the question, but also for providing the example.